# How do I select multiple components in the NetBeans UI builder on a Mac?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

When I am building a gui in NetBeans on a Mac, sometimes I want to select multiple components and move them together, delete them together, copy them together, or whatever.  In Windows I would hold down the Ctrl key.  On a Mac I usually (for other applications) hold down the Command key.  Neither of these works in NetBeans 7.0 on a Mac.  Is there a key modifier for selections on Mac in Netbeans?

I'm not sure the name of the gui builder in Netbeans, maybe it is called a ui editor or gui editor.  Just thought I'd throw that in for people searching with the term "editor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in the "customize layout" frame for the GridBags layout, Ctrl-Alt click will allow multiple selection.  But this doesn't work in the main editor.